# angular js tab key not working on state change for form field focus

Tags: angularjs, tabs, focus, field, state

i have a page with form fields. 
Now when i go to this page using angular state change event, the tab key press does not take the cursor to next form field, whereas the tab key works when i refresh the page.

The page state is: 
    ui-sref="app.spviewform"

Here is the HTML

```
<input name="inputText" type="text" tabindex="1" ng-model="inputText" validator-required="true" validator-group="" id="default_2" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" placeholder="" validator="[number]">
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some code?

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue did you find the way to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Haven't got clean angular way but found a workaround. i reloaded the page using a function which triggers on ng-click with a timout of 10miliseconds.
Like this:
`$timeout(function(){
            location.reload();
        },10);`